# SQL Server calculation gives unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very weird scenario which i am sure the is an explanation for.

I trying to calculate something and here is the values:

```
 SELECT 145.28/63 *(8 * 100) / 100 -- returns: 18.4482480000
```

The problem is that this is not correct, If i do the calculation with Windows Calculator then it returns a more precise value:

145,28/63 *(8 - 0 * 100) / 100 = 18,44825396825397

I had to change a lot to get it work with SQL Server:

```
SELECT 145.28  * 100 * 8 / (100 * 63) --RETURNS: 18.4482539682539
```

How come i need to change the numbers in SQL Server but not in windows?

In Navision programming it returns the correct value which is 18.4482539682539682

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the default datatype that is automatically assigned simply doesnt hold the precision you want. This can easily be fixed by explicitly casting your first number as a more precise datatype like this:

```
SELECT CAST(145.28 AS decimal(38,35))/63 *(8 * 100) / 100 
--returns 18.448253968253968253968253
```

From there on out sql server understand not to downcast it so the result becomes 18.448253968253968253968253

syntax for decimal is decimal(total positions,of which after comma). don't forget that the comma takes a place as well.

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) for docu.

If you want to limit the decimals you can use ROUND like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(145.28 AS float)/63 *(8 * 100) / 100,12)
```

The maximum precision you can achieve in sql server (as a single value anyway) is
18.448253968253968253968253

per linked docu from ms:

**decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]**
Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.

Comment: Changed your query to SELECT CAST(145.28 AS decimal(38,20))*100 * 8 / (100 * 63)  which gave me a more precise result: 18.44825396825396, but i want to this value:18.44825396825396820000

Comment: @Tristan I was trying to calculate the final precision and scale for this expression, then came back and ... you really nailed it. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

The result's precision is calculated [based on some factors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) that may give you a scale lower than what you expect. Just try this one:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 35), 145.28)/63 *(8 * 100)
```

which will give you

```
1844.825396825396825396825397
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with precision. When you do 145.28/63 in Sql it evaluates to 2.306031. If you do it in windows calculator it evaluates to 2.3060317460317460317460317460317. So your multiplying different numbers thus the difference in the result.

To get the same result as in Navision try using a decimal with really high precision:

```
SELECT cast(145.28 as decimal(35,30))/63 *(8 * 100) / 100
```

It evalueates to 18.4482539682539682

Comment: Thank you, then how do I get the all the 20 decimals?

Comment: @user3514987 - first, take a step back and consider whether you *need* 20 decimals of precision. *most* applications don't require that much precision, and if you do need it, SQL may not be the correct language to be working in. And there aren't "all" 20 decimals - the expression computes a value that has a recurring decimal representation. You could equally ask for "all" 40 decimals, or "all" 100000000 decimals.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, as you can see in my answer 20 positions is very doable in sql server.

Comment: @Tristan - yes, but I was trying to point out that you can have as many repeats of `968253` as you want and 20 positions is no more "correct" than 10 positions or 40, and also that it's quite uncommon to actually *need* 20 positions - so I was trying to prompt the OP to consider what their actual requirements are here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's a very valid point to make, slightly irrelevant considering the requirement fits in the specs of the software, but valid none the less. It just wasnt that clear to me from your comment ;)

Answer (score -1):

Here Your execution steps are creating this difference. You can try this for achiving the same result.

```
SELECT 145.28 *(8 * 100)/63 / 100;
```

Which will resulted as `18.4482539600.`

Comment: OP was already able to reorder operations. Actually he/she included improved query in the question